# Contact Form without PHP or any other server language

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, css

Hello from the Great Russia!

I have the following contact form...

```
<form class="orderForm" action="">
    <p><input type="text" name="" placeholder="Name" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="" placeholder="Phone number" required="required" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="" placeholder="E-mail address" required="required" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="" value="Send Request" /></p>
    </form>
```

Is it possible to save data from the form to the .txt file or smth like that? I mean is it possible to make this form work and send emails without any PHP or without any other server language!? Only HTML.

Maybe the submitted form could be somehow saved into the files? .TXT or other...?

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: Nope. I think you should make normal `name` attributes, and take info with php and put it in TXT (actually, you should use MySQL...).

Answer (score 0):

Please understand, for any server side interaction you will have to use the server side languages like JSP,PHP,ASP or any other. As per your requirement goes, you need to send emails which can be done only by a server. You can't do a job of a server by using just client side scripting. i.e : plain HTML,JS for your case. If you want to use JS as a server side language check [Node.js](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/)